# How to implement base class member functions with a dynamic array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, polymorphism

I am trying to figure out the correct way of implementing base class member functions with a dynamic array of objects (using an array of pointers to the base class). I have an animal base class, with reptile and mammal derived from that, and then multiple other derived classes from those two. I tried running the following code through gdb and it gave me a segmentation fault specifically when I tried going through case four on the switch.

```
class Zoo
{
    Animal ** _zoo;

public:
    Zoo();
    ~Zoo();
    void Run();
};
#endif

const unsigned MAX_ZOO = 20;

Zoo::Zoo()
{
    _zoo = new Animal*[MAX_ZOO];
}

Zoo::~Zoo(){}

void Zoo::Run()
{
    unsigned pick = 1;
    unsigned element = 0;
    unsigned choose;
    while (pick != 5)
    {
        pick = select_option();
        switch (pick)
        {
    case 1:
           cout << "Is the animal a mammal(1) or reptile(2)?" << endl;
           cin >> choose;
           if (choose == 1)
           {
            cout << "Is this animal an elephant(1), skunk(2), or other(3)?"      << endl;
            cin >> choose;
            if (choose == 1)
                _zoo[element] = new Elephant();
            else if (choose == 2)
                _zoo[element] = new Skunk();
            else
                _zoo[element] = new Mammal();
           }
           else if (choose == 2)
           {
            cout << "Is this animal a python(1), crocodilia(2), or other(3)?" << endl;
                cin >> choose;
                if (choose == 1)
                    _zoo[element] = new Python();
                else if (choose == 2)
                    _zoo[element] = new Crocodilia();
                else
                    _zoo[element] = new Reptile();
           }
       element += 1;
       break;
    case 2:
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < element; i++)
            _zoo[element]->Feed();
        break;
    case 3:
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < element; i++)
            _zoo[element]->CageMaintenance();
        break;
    case 4:
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < element; i++)
            _zoo[element]->Display();
        break;
    }
}
```

Is that the correct way of implementing the base class functions?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>` ? (And respect rule of 0)

Comment: You are using `unsigned pick` before initializing it.

Comment: @Mohamad Elghawi I just tried initializing it and still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: We'll need more information then. When does it crash? What inputs are you passing into the application when it crashes. What errors does your debugger report?

Comment: "Is that the correct way of implementing the base class functions?" I don't know; you don't show them.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation `Display()` for whatever class you're trying to call `Display()` on?